# Excel Data move keeping function argument code in the same cell after the movement of data

Tags: vba, excel

Excel vba: one workbook with 12 sheets, Jan - Dec, with Years 2011,2012,2013 and 2014,One Comparison sheet. 
My current fields with data B4-D11,B14-D24,B28-d29, and H4-H11,h14-h24,h28-h29
Code now when asked will move h to d, d to c c to b with will also rename a1 on each sheet for the current year.. my trouble is on the comparison sheet in the above fields i use the =SUM('*'!bxx) and so on to update the page, but when i move the data on this sheet, the code =SUM('*'!bxx) go's away. can any one help I need the code to stay in each cell...
Thank you in advance for any help..

Comment: Presentation is not just for chefs.

Comment: No solution, because moving cell make fumction loosing cells references.

Comment: Thanks for the answer after much research I came up with the same approaching it a different way thank you

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/users/3131905/dacrovinunghi Answered this question . I've rewritten the code to move just the years on the comparison page as the data like will place the correct data in the correct year